# Java Binary search not working

Tags: java, search, binary, insertion-sort

I have an insertion search in the main and from there I call the BinarySearch method to search for a number within the array that has already been sorted. I try to compile it I get errors here is my main with the insertion sort.

```
public class test5
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

// original order or numbers
System.out.println("Original order of numbers:");
int nums[] = {26, 45, 56, 12, 78, 74, 39, 22, 5, 90, 87, 32, 28, 11, 93, 62, 79, 53, 22, 51};

for(int x = 0; x < nums.length; x++){
System.out.print(nums[x] + " ");
}


// local variables
int unsortedValue; // The first unsorted value
int scan; // used to scan the array
int swapCount = 0;


// the other loop steps the index variable through 
// each subscript in the array, starting at 1. This
// is because element 0 is considered already sorted.
for(int index = 1; index < nums.length; index++)
{
    // The first element outside the sorted subset is
    // nums[index]. Store the value of this elementt
    // in unsortedValue.
    unsortedValue = nums[index];

    // Start the scan at the subscript of the first element
    // into its proper position within the sorted subset.
    scan = index;

    // Move the first element outside the sorted subset
    // into its proper position within the sorted subset.
    while(scan > 0 && nums[scan-1] > unsortedValue)
    {
        nums[scan] = nums[scan -1];
        scan--;

    }

    // Insert the unsorted value in its proper position
    // within the sorted subset.
    nums[scan] = unsortedValue;
    swapCount++;
        }

    //  print out results of swap and swapCount
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Insertion sort: ");

    for(int index = 0; index < nums.length; index++){   
            System.out.print(nums[index] + " ");
                        }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The swap count is: " + swapCount);
    BinarySearch(nums);
    }
```

Here is the method for the binary search

```
public static int BinarySerach(String[] array, String value)
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter target: ");
int target = nums.nextInt();
int index = -1;
int left = 0;
int right = nums.length - 1; 
int middle;
while(left <= right){
    middle = (left + right)/2;
    if(nums[middle] == target){
        index = middle;
        break;
    } else if (nums[middle] > target) {
        right = middle - 1;
    }else{
        left = middle + 1;
    }
}
if(index == -1){
    System.out.println("element not found");
}else{
    System.out.println("element found at index " + index);
    }
}
```

}

Errors I get are cannot find symbol.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.  The error is most likely self-explanatory from there

Comment: hmm stack trace. I am not sure what that means I will have to look it up. Does that have to do with Jgrasp?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your `nums` array locally inside your `main` method, so it's inaccessible anywhere else, e.g. your `BinarySearch` method.  The scope is only within the `main` method.

Declare it `static` outside of all methods so it can be accessed from any method:

```
public class test5
{
    static int nums[] = {26, 45, 56, 12, 78, 74, 39, 22, 5, 90, 87, 32, 28, 11, 93, 62, 79, 53, 22, 51};

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    ...
```

Additionally,

- You can't call `nextInt` on an `int[]` (nums).  It looks like you
  meant to call it on `Scanner` object: `int target =
  keyboard.nextInt();`
- You aren't using any of the arguments to `BinarySearch` - remove them.  Also remove passing `nums` in your call to `BinarySearch`.
- It's probably a typo here, but you declared your method here `BinarySerach` instead of `BinarySearch`.
- You aren't returning anything from your `BinarySearch` method, but you aren't assigning the return of that method to anything either; just make the return type `void`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by assigning the return. I am confused as to where I should place that. and should it be something like return false; ??

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
class BinarySearch{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (isr);
int a[]={7, 10, 12, 34, 45,51, 60, 78, 81, 92};
int key, low=0, high=a.length-1, mid=0;
System.out.print("Enter the integer to search:");        key=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
while(low<=high){
mid=(low+high)/2;
if (key==a[mid])
break;
else if(key<a[mid])
high=mid-1;
else
low=mid+1;
}
if(low<=high)
System.out.println(key+" found at index "+mid);
else
System.out.println(key+" not found");
}
}``
```

Comment: Hi there gamerboy, welcome to Stack Exchange and thank you for your answer. Do you think you could expand upon your answer with a bit more of an explanation of how or why this fixes the problem? Also, it would be a lot better if you could format your code to make it more readable. Thanks.

Comment: Explain more your question.